# Docker cerbot unable to renew ssl certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, tls1.2

I have my VPS online with my project live, with a SSL certificate, that I need to renew because I need SSH in order for it ti properly function. Here is the problem: I am not able to renew it.

In my docker compose file, there is the nginx configuration, and here is the code:

```
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    environment:
      - CERTBOT_EMAIL=my.email@gmail.com
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - www-certs:/etc/letsencrypt
```

Here is the docker image configurations:

```
FROM staticfloat/nginx-certbot:latest

# Copy our custom nginx config
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And then I set up all the nginx configurations in the default.conf file in the following way:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.my-table.it www.api.my-table.it localhost;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name api.my-table.it www.api.my-table.it localhost 127.0.0.1;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it/privkey.pem;

    charset utf-8;

    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;


    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 512M;  

    # add the responde for the ACME challenge
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_table:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

And when I hit `docker-compose up` all starts to load, but the challenge fails. Now I will copy some of the output code I get:

```
nginx_1     | Waiting for verification...
nginx_1     | 2023/05/29 19:08:28 [error] 23#23: *1 open() "/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.149.190.27, server: api.my-table.it, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg HTTP/1.1", host: "api.my-table.it"
nginx_1     | 54.149.190.27 - - [29/May/2023:19:08:28 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)" "-"
nginx_1     | 2023/05/29 19:08:28 [error] 23#23: *2 open() "/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 23.178.112.106, server: api.my-table.it, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg HTTP/1.1", host: "api.my-table.it"
nginx_1     | 23.178.112.106 - - [29/May/2023:19:08:28 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)" "-"
nginx_1     | 2023/05/29 19:08:28 [error] 23#23: *3 open() "/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 3.19.218.166, server: api.my-table.it, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg HTTP/1.1", host: "api.my-table.it"
nginx_1     | 3.19.218.166 - - [29/May/2023:19:08:28 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Ze82Yq4XNerlLnxaH479HG1NfcOIdEwZfEyH-I4nxqg HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)" "-"
nginx_1     | Challenge failed for domain api.my-table.it
nginx_1     | http-01 challenge for api.my-table.it
nginx_1     | Cleaning up challenges
```

It looks like there is no correct /var/www/html/ directory, but I dont' know why, since I created the certificate, and never touched it again

Can someone please help me figuring out and fix it? Please

Comment: Note that the image you're using appears to be unmaintained. The docker hub entry says, "NOTE: This repository is now in maintenance-only mode". The last update was over two years ago.